# Max a Sum of a partition by

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I have the below table.

I would like to SUM hours and partition by id then take the `Max` hours per custid. Below is what I have so far.

TableA

```
id    custid    projid   hours
 1      1010     Yellow    1
 1      1011     Yellow    2
 1      1012     Yellow    5
 1      1010     Yellow    5
```

SQL:

```
select SUM(HOURS)OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY cust) AS TOTAL_HRS
from tablea
```

Expected Output: The above SQL does not capture `MAX` hours

```
id    custid  projid  hours
 1      1010   Yellow  6
```

Comment: Your question is lacking a question.

Comment: That was fast! I'm not sure why it didn't show the first time, but the question is editied.

Comment: Also, why do you expect the data in that single row?  You've thrown a rabbit at us.

Comment: To perform an aggregate on an analytic simply wrap the analytic in a subquery/derived dable/cte and then select the max sum.  You need the results of the analytic to be calculated before you can get the max sum, thus the reason to wrap as a derived table.  Order of operations of SQL prevents you from doing both; thus introduction of the derived table/cte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `SUM` as an analytic function usually means that you want to find a sum while retaining all your original records.  But your expected output seems to imply an aggregation.  So, I suggest using `GROUP BY`, and then querying that to find the row with the highest hours.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, custid, projid, SUM(hours) AS hours
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY id, custid, projid
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
ORDER BY hours DESC
WHERE rownum = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You want one more `partition` :

```
select *, sum(hours) over (partition by id, custid, projid order by cust) AS TOTAL_HRS
from tablea t
order by sum(hours) over (partition by id, custid, projid order by cust) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if this does what you really want:

```
select cust, sum(hours) as total_hours
from tablea
order by sum(hours)
fetch first 1 row only;
```

It is unclear why you need the other values in the row.  If you do, you could aggregate them into a single row.